# URL naviation using Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, url-routing

I am a newbie of JS and Jquery, I am trying to figure out a way to using conditional navigation to URL using Radio buttons.

I have two options in my form one for selecting the Criteria and the other for selecting the matching yes/no.

depending on the Radio button selections made, I have to provide URLs to those reports like the Param2 + No = Report 1 URL and et al.

Is there a way to achieve that with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form name="formone" id="optionsform">
    <fieldset>
      <p><b>Selection Criteria</b></p>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="ac-yes" value="1">Param1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="ac-no" value="0">Param2</label>
  <p><b>Auto Matching</b></p>
<label><input type="radio" name="group2" id="bt-yes" value="2">Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="group2" id="bt-no" value="0">No</label>
  <p></p>
<a href="varible-address">Go</a>
</fieldset>
</form>
<script>
    $(function(){
      var urls = new Array();
      urls[0]="Report 1 URL";// no + no
      urls[1]="Report 2 URL";// yes + no
      urls[2]="Report 3 URL";// no + yes
      urls[3]="Report 4 URL";// yes + yes

      $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        var score = 0;
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){score+=parseInt($(this).val())});) before the the curly bracket
        $('a').attr('href',urls[score]);
      });) and ;
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I would appropriate if someone could tell me how to use a Go button rather than this Link href.

If this is not possible can we use Javascript instead?

Here is the JSbin : http://jsbin.com/emaxev/1/edit

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script seems to have some bad closed `)` and text that is not commented out.

Fixing that and the function works fine

```
$(function () {
    var urls = new Array();
    urls[0] = "Report 1 URL"; // no + no
    urls[1] = "Report 2 URL"; // yes + no
    urls[2] = "Report 3 URL"; // no + yes
    urls[3] = "Report 4 URL"; // yes + yes

    $('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
        var score = 0;
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function () {
            score += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('a').attr('href', urls[score]);
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/RyQuj/1/

If you want to make a button use `<button>`.

```
<button>Go</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Spokey for the response. I am trying the Go button click within my application with the URLS in place however, it is not going to those URL's but just passing the parameters group1=1&group2=0 to the URL which is not I was looking for. I was basically just trying to navigate to that URLS based on the score of selections.

Comment: Also please excuse my ignorance but is there any way to convert this into Javascript as my application understands that better than Jquery yeah its an old one :(

Comment: Are you submitting the form? normally it should not give you `'group1=1&group2=0'`. Anyway I made a normal javascript one here in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/RyQuj/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help Spokey, you are really good at this and may be I should take this at my inspiration to becoming good at JavaScript'in. Yes I am submitting the form and after I submit it goes to www.mydomain.com:port/app/group1=1&group2=0, however I was thinking document.getElementById("go").href = urls[score]; will take me to that url for that score. And my urls[0] = www.mydomain.com:port/app/report1 , urls[1] = www.mydomain.com:port/app/report2 , urls[2] = www.mydomain.com:port/app/report3 , and urls[4] = www.mydomain.com:port/app/report4

Comment: if you just want to redirect the page you don't have to submit the results of the checkbox. can you show the full html and js again? or are you only using `<input type='submit'/>`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Spokey, here is the JSBin where I am trying at : http://jsbin.com/ilewed/1/edit and also my original intent of doing the URL based on score is, I were to select one of the Param2 from selection criteria and Yes from Auto Matching then it should navigate that report page were I have developed, similarly for other values for I have 4 reports in total that I want the user to navigate by evaluating the Radio button values.

Comment: Try this http://jsbin.com/ilewed/2/edit. Note that I removed the Go link and added `action` to the `form`, then instead of changing the url of the link you change the action of the `form`. For more info on this see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp under `submit button`

Comment: Thanks a lot Spokey. You are the Guru and I really appreciate all your answers. I will read those links you have suggested and next time will ask better questions.